# CLISP: variable <x> has no value when returning from function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I'm running into the following problem in Common Lisp (using CLISP)... The following code runs just fine and as expected ('->' designates what the function call returns):

```
(list (quote x)) -> (X)
```

However, when I try to move this behavior into a function,

```
(defun quote-it (x) 
    (list (quote x)))
```

And I call the function, I get an unexpected error.

```
(quote-it x) -> SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT: variable X has no value
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you compile `quote-it`, you will get a warning that you are not using the value of the argument `x`. This should serve as a, well, warning that something is amiss.

Specifically, Common Lisp [evaluates](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/sec_3-1-2-1.html) the expression `(quote-it x)` by, first, evaluating `x`, and, second, passing the result to `quote-it`. Since you never gave `x` a value, the first step fails.

Try these:

```
(defparameter x 42)
(quote-it x)
==> (x)
(quote-it 'y)
==> (x)
```

As you can see, it does not matter what you pass to `quote-it`.

PS: generally speaking, the special operator [`quote`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_quote.htm) is rarely used in *functions*. It is a common tool in *macros* though, as suggested by a commenter:

```
(defmacro quote-it (x) `(list ',x))
```

If you tell us what you *want* to achieve (in a separate question), we (the SO community) might be of more help.

Comment: Good explanation, but I think a macro probably does what you want: (defmacro quote-it (x)
           `(list (quote ,x)))

Answer (score 0):

First it evaluates `(QUOTE-IT X)`.

For that it evaluates `X`.

`X` has no value.

You can easily see this in the *backtrace* or the *stepper*:

**CLISP Backtrace.**

```
Break 1 [5]> :bt
<1/153> #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION SHOW-STACK> 3
<2/146> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SYSTEM::PRINT-BACKTRACE>
<3/140> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SYSTEM::DEBUG-BACKTRACE>
<4/131> #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT> 2
<5/128> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SYSTEM::BREAK-LOOP-2-3>
<6/124> #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION SYSTEM::SAME-ENV-AS> 2
<7/110> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SYSTEM::BREAK-LOOP-2>
<8/108> #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION SYSTEM::DRIVER>
<9/68> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SYSTEM::BREAK-LOOP>
<10/65> #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION INVOKE-DEBUGGER> 1
<11/55> #<SYSTEM-FUNCTION ERROR>
<12/42> #<COMPILED-FUNCTION SYSTEM::CHECK-VALUE>
[39] EVAL frame for form X
[34] EVAL frame for form (QUOTE-IT X)
```

**CLISP stepper**

```
[10]> (step (quote-it x))
step 1 --> (QUOTE-IT X)
Step 1 [11]> :s             ; <--- STEP
step 2 --> X                
Step 2 [12]> :S             ; <--- STEP

*** - EVALHOOK: variable X has no value
The following restarts are available:
USE-VALUE      :R1      Input a value to be used instead of X.
STORE-VALUE    :R2      Input a new value for X.
ABORT          :R3      Abort main loop
```